# setText() and addItem() of lineEdit and QlistWidget respectively do not show the contents

Tags: for-loop, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlineedit, qlistwidget

I want to display the value stored in the varible "total" to the QlineEdit and add value of the variable 'points' to the QlistWidget when the button is clicked.

In the following block of code, i used "self.lineEdit.setText(str(points))" and "self.LW2.addItem(self.points)" to set text to QlineEdit and QlistWidget respectively. Still, the values won't show up.

```
def display(self):    
        sqlC = self.databaseConn()
        #self.playersList = []
        self.pointlist = []
        self.total = 0
        self.economic_rate=0 
        if "----SELECT TEAM----" == self.CB1.currentText():
            self.msgbox("Warning","Select a team to evaluate")
        else:    
            for x in range(self.LW1.count()):
                player=self.LW1.item(x).text()
                #print(player)
                sqlC.execute("SELECT Scored,Faced,Fours,Sixes,Bowled,Wkts,Catches,Stumping,RO,Given FROM Match WHERE Player = ?",(player,))
                score=sqlC.fetchall()
                points = FantasyCricket.FantasyCricket.BattingBowlingPoints.batting(score)
                points += FantasyCricket.FantasyCricket.BattingBowlingPoints.bowling(score)
                self.pointlist.append(points)
                
                
                #print(points)
                self.total += points
                #print(self.total)
                self.LW2.addItem(str(points))
        self.lineEdit.setText(str(self.total))
```

P.S- the values are displayed correctly on the Shell using print()

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Class definition missing. Please show definition of `lineEdit`, `LW2` and where the method `display` is called.